# How can I retrieve the most represented value in column of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm working on a dataframe similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(seqid = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D"),
             value = c("100", "50", "20", "7", "7", "7", "100", "100", "50", "50", "7", "7", "100"))
```

I would like to get the name of the seqids where I found the value 100 and the value 7 several times.
In this case the output would be "B" and "C".

It might also be useful for me to add a command that makes me choose seqids in which those values are contained more than n times.

For example the value 100 found more than 10 times and the value 7 more than 10 or 5 times.

I've already tried "dplyr" with group_by(seqid) and "data.table" but I can't get the output I want.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: You could add additional columns with `ifelse` to test whether `value==7` or `value==100` then use a cumsum function to the new columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(value, seqid) %>% 
  filter(value %in% c(7, 100) & n() > 1) %>%
  count()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   value, seqid [3]
#>   value seqid     n
#>  <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1 100   B         2
#> 2 7     B         3
#> 3 7     D         2
```

Or if you just want the unique `seqid` values then

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(value, seqid) %>%
  filter(value %in% c(7, 100) & n() > 1) %>%
  count() %>%
  getElement(2) %>%
  unique()
#> [1] "B" "D"
```

Comment: How can I select only the seqids where there is both the value 100 and 7 > n time? I don't want seqids where there is only one of two values..thanks a lot!

Comment: @cucalorda change `n() > 1` to `n() > 3`, or whatever threshold you want.